# PROGRESS 4GL Multiple browse - focus at row

Tags: progress-4gl

I have problem with browse widget and "FOCUS".
I know "VALUE-CHANGED" event but it doesn't work on multiple selection browse how i want. 
On focus of row i want to display some details about that row but with documentation I think that there is no event for "FOCUS on a ROW).
ROW-ENTRY also don't work.

So with my keyboard I try to focus on row (display under some details) and then i can select it or no.

This is my code.

```
DEF VAR v_isSelected AS LOG INITIAL FALSE.

DEF BROWSE b2 QUERY q2
DISPLAY 
    {&FIELDS}
WITH 9 DOWN NO-BOX AT COLUMN 1 ROW 5 OVERLAY WIDTH 78 MULTIPLE.

ON "ROW-ENTRY" OF b2 
DO: 
    v_isSelected = BROWSE b2:IS-ROW-SELECTED(BROWSE b2:FOCUSED-ROW). 
    BROWSE b2:SELECT-FOCUSED-ROW().

    RUN det_b2(b2:HANDLE).
    IF v_isSelected = FALSE THEN BROWSE b2:DESELECT-FOCUSED-ROW().
END.
```

Regards and thank You for help.

e: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P130192
This is answer from progress dev. I had hope that is some trigger, but there isn't.

Comment: What I have done wrong to get -1 ?

Comment: Ok. Now i understand :}
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P130192 its official response from progress developer.

Comment: You'll have better luck tagging questions "progress-4gl" rather than plain old "progress".